# How to access a form value in Redux dispatch?

Tags: react-redux, redux-saga

I have the following form component:

```
export class LoginPage extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={this.props.onSubmitForm}>
          <Input id="username" type="text" value={this.props.username} />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Just after the component I have a `mapDispatchToProps` function:

```
export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onSubmitForm: (evt) => {
      // I need to access the `username` property here to pass it as argument.
      dispatch(postUsername(username));
    },
  };
}
```

I need to access the `username` inside the `mapDispatchToProps` function.
What is the simplest way to do it? I don't need to store the `username` in this step.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `event.target.username.value` property, so your code should look like this:

```
export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onSubmitForm: (evt) => {
      // I need to access the `username` property here to pass it as argument.
      dispatch(postUsername(evt.target.username.value));
    },
  };
}
```

By doing this you should have the username value.

Comment: Thank you, it is actually `evt.target.username.value` in this case.